# How to access current value from writable?

Tags: sveltekit

I want to create a custom wrapper for [i18n](https://www.i18next.com/) to translate content of the site by clicking the lang button.

Currently, I have something like this.

```html
<script>
  import { localization } from './localiztion.ts';
</script>

<p>{localization.t("hello")}</p>
<button on:click={localization.toggleLocale}></button>
```

`p` which holds a text (which should be translated) and `button` which triggers translation.

To split logic from UI I moved localization logic into a different file. It looks like this

```js
const resources = {
    "en": {
        "hello": "Hello",
    },
    "uk": {
        "hello": "Привіт"
    }
}

export function createLocalization() {
    let store = writable("en");

    return {
        unsubscribe: store.unsubscribe,
        toggleLocale: () => {
            store.update((previousLocale) => {
                let nextLocale = previousLocale === "en" ? "uk" : "en";

                return nextLocale;
            });
        },
        t: (key: string): string => {
            // How to get access to the current store value and return it back to UI?
            // I need to do something like this
            return resources[store][key]
        }
    }
}

export const localization = createLocalization();
```

The problem I have I need to access the current local from within a `t` function. How can I do this?

I could pass it from UI like

```js
// cut

<p>{localization.t("hello", $localization)}</p>

// cut
```

by doing this I achieve what I want, but the solution is too cumbersome.

Any advice on how I can do this?

Comment: (Stores have no `unsubscribe` method. The function to unsubscribed is returned by a call to `subscribe`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the store value via [`get`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get), but this is be a bad idea, as it would lose reactivity. I.e. a language change would not update your text on the page.

A better approach is defining it as a store. Since stores currently have to be at the top level to be used with `$` syntax, it is more ergonomic to split it into a separate [`derived`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-derived) store:

```js
export let locale = writable("en"); // Wrap it to restrict it more
export let translate = derived(
  locale,
  $locale => key => resources[$locale][key],
);
```

This way you can import this store, which contains a function for translating keys:

```js
import { translate } from '...';
// ...
$translate('hello')
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5f5322e5b22c4098b5cf5a5545cd77c8?version=3.52.0)

(The stores can of course also be created differently and e.g. injected via a context instead of importing them.)